# What is the best practice for running a scheduler or delayed job on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, cron, redis, delayed-job

I've seen several solutions for doing this:

1. Redis / Resque
2. Delayed Job
3. Heroku Scheduler
4. Clockwork

Heroku scheduler won't work because it runs at random times and only once per 10 minutes at its most frequent.

Running on Cedar. Running multiple web dynos.

EDIT: Here's what I want to do:
Call an arbitrary method with params at an arbitrary point in the future. Something like `Schedule.set(Notification.send_update_to_user(574), Time.now + 1.days)`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you need a scheduler, a job queue, or a scheduler that puts jobs in a queue? If ten minutes isn't frequent enough, what is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at different options, I chose Delayed Job, which is well documented on Heroku.

For jobs that need to run at a certain time each day or once an hour, Heroku scheduler works well, but sometimes it doesn't run.

Answer (score 3):

I would choose Sidekiq, though there are several other options suitable for your example. Sidekiq lets you [schedule jobs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs) to run at arbitrary times in the future:

```
NotificationUpdateWorker.perform_at(Time.now + 1.day, 574)
```

The [delayed extensions](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-extensions) would let you write instead:

```
Notification.delay_for(1.day).send_update_to_user(574)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with rufus/scheduler.

require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

scheduler.every '1m' do
  Checkin.check_checkin()
end